# Includes and namespaces

Tags: c++, namespaces

I have a file named **header1.h** with the following code

```
#include "string.h"

namespace custom1
{

    #define MYMACRO(f, z) strrchr(f, z)
}
```

but now I'm getting compilation errors with gcc like

> OtherHeader.h error: there are no arguments to â€˜strrchrâ€™ that
>   depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of â€˜strrchrâ€™ must
>   be available [-fpermissive]

Why isn't the "string.h" inclusion visible? Can another file do this

```
namespace custom1
{
  is MYMACRO visibile here?
}
```

?

Why am I getting the depend error?

Comment: `strrchr` takes two parameters. There's is some context missing in your code, I doubt a macro definition alone can trigger this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preprocessor macros have no notion of namespaces, they do 'global text processing', always.

Answer (score 0):

The signature of the strrchr function is

```
char *strrchr(const char *s, int c);
```

so I think you are just missing an argument.